# How do I make UIWebView scroll to the top?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to make a UIWebView scroll to the top when I touch say a UISearchView within the same viewController (without using Javascript).

Something like this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
      [myWebView scrollToTop];    //pseudocode 

}
```

In other words, what happens when I touch the top bar can also happen programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *don't* want to use JavaScript there's no public API method to do this. UIWebViews don't inherit from scroll views, so you can't use any of the usual methods. As you've figured out, it's possible to do with JavaScript. You can try to find the actual scroll view in the UIWebView, but it's all undocumented and not really a good thing to do in a production app.

**Update** - as of iOS 5 you can now get direct access to a web view's `UIScrollView` - see Reconquistador's answer for more information.

Comment: This was true prior to iOS 5. See Reconquistador's answer below for an up-to-date solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11796354/1148702) that uses the publicly accessible `scrollView` property of `UIWebView`.

Comment: Very true! Post iOS 5 you can now change this.

Answer (score 26):

```
CGPoint top = CGPointMake(0, 0); // can also use CGPointZero here
[myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:top animated:YES];
```

(Note that if you have set `myWebView.scrollView.contentInset.top` you will want to take that into account instead of just scrolling to CGPointZero.)

Comment: I have tested it at 5.1 and 6.0 and its working at both of them

Comment: True. I have tested it at iOS4 few days ago and its not working

Answer (score 7):

Here's a really ugly, terrible way to do this. I'm answering this to show you what never to do.

```
for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        [(UIScrollView*)subview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: OP is asking how to scroll a UIWebView to 0,0. How its triggered is irrelevant.

Comment: This does actually work. I think I'll stick with the JavaScript method :-) Is there actually a reason not to do other than it looks like a hack?

Comment: +1 This should be accepted answer. It's not ugly nor terrible. It can only fail when Apple changes UIWebView's view hierarchy, but who can imagine a web view without scroll view ;)

Answer (score 6):

Scroll the UIWebView by calling JavaScript through Objective-C:

```
NSString *script = @"scrollTo(0, 0)";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

For smooth scrolling, use a library like jQuery:

```
NSString *script = @"$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow')";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

Answer (score 5):

Access the `UIWebView`'s **`scrollview`** and set **YES** to method **`scrollsToTop`**;

```
WebView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.x**

```
webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you will find any officially supported method to do what you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
//[scrollView setContentOffset: topOffset animated: YES];
[[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

Where webView is the subclass of the UIWebView, of course.

Answer (score 0):

why not just touch the status bar of your device. for all the scrollView based controls, tableView, webView, scrollView, there is a :
The scroll-to-top gesture is a tap on the status bar; when this property is YES, the scroll view jumps to the top of the content when this gesture occurs. The default value of this property is YES.

Answer (score -3):

Displaying a PDF in a UIWebView, I found you can jump to the top simply by reloading the document.

Comment: That's a very expensive way of doing this?